# Downgrade Visual Studio 2017 15.5 to previous version 15.4.4?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

TIFU by upgrading to the latest Visual Studio 15.5 which breaks too many things.

Is it possible to downgrade Visual Studio 2017 from 15.5 to the previous version, 15.4.4 ?

I tried un-installing VS2017 and re-install it, but it goes straight to the latest version.

Any way to do this ?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Comment: Nice, my google-fu was lacking this morning. put that in an answer and I will vote it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Hans should probably take credit for this, but here's the link to properly downgrade: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

v15.5 also screwed things up for me and I had to uninstall.